# BLUEMIX support for Social media app

Tags: ibm-cloud, social-media

I'm building a social media app targeting a specific nitche of users.

The app is built in HTML5 with features similar to Facebook or Instagram.

Can the entire application run on Bluemix?

What exactly are the benefits of bluemix to an App of this nature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Blumix is a PAAS. The benefits of Bluemix are the benefits of a PAAS infrastructure and of the support:

- cost savings
- reduced technical maintenance

The upfront costs for purchasing servers, other hardware, and the necessary software licenses are eliminated.

**Technical Benefits**

- Choice to choose the programming models, languages, operating systems and databases
- Switching in different environments – Development , Test ( System, Integration, UAT,etc)
- Hardware Scalability -  Auto scaling supported through DevOps Services
- Elasticity   -  Supported through DevOps Services
      Automation – Supported at various level from runtime provisioning to development lifecycle
      Improved development productivity

**Business benefits**

- Lower Total Cost of Ownership
- Faster time to market
- Business Continuity
- Savings on costs associated with hardware resource consumption and support infrastructure

Facebook is a social network. 
And yes you can do something like this on Bluemix choosing the right services. I suggest you to take a look at Bluemix Catalog in order to understand what services you can create and use on Bluemix to do what you want: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/
In this particular case I suggest you to take a look to Object Storage Service (to store files) - DashDB (or other db service) to store db information - SSO to manage the authentication.

I suggest to take a look at this article too: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Moving_to_Cloud_Platform_as_a_Service_Pros_and_Cons?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

This a quite large topic, however let's see some of the services you could use on Bluemix developing your application:

- the first thing I think about is the [IBM Graph](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/ibm-graph/) service: it is an easy-to-use, fully-managed NO-SQL graph database service for storing and querying data points, their connections, and properties. IBM Graph offers an Apache TinkerPop3 compatible API and plugs into your Bluemix application seamlessly. This service can be used for building recommendation engines, analyzing social networks, and fraud detection.
- [Insights for Twitter](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/insights-for-twitter/): this could be useful if you need to integrate with Twitter for example analyzing the trends and providing your users updated news.
- You could take a look at the Watson cognitive services in the [Bluemix Catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/), some of them can be useful for social networking purposes (eg. [Language Translation](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/language-translation/) to connect people speaking different languages, or [Personality Insights](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/personality-insights/) to identify psychological traits which determine purchase decisions, intent and behavioral traits).

The application can entirely run on Bluemix (you can choose the Runtime you prefer for the server-side code). The benefits, in addition to the services listed above (there are actually many others that could result useful), are the classic ones related to developing on a Cloud PaaS platform: scalability (both horizontal and vertical), availability, lower costs...